# Has there ever been an antonym for "benefit" that includes the latin affix "neg-"?

Tags: etymology, antonyms, latin

I understand *bene* to roughly mean *well, good,* or *rightly so* from Latin, while *neg-* coming from Latin *negare* to roughly mean *deny, negate,* or *against*.

The words *benefit*, *beneficial*, and *benefactor* all represent a person or characteristic that yields a positive result or influence.  Do any of these words have an antonym that includes the *neg-* affix?  Are there any positive *bene*-based words that have a *neg*-based word as its antonym?

*Mono-* and *poly-* seem to be frequently paired in an antonymic relationship — does this occur with *bene-* and *neg-*?

*Background:  I started titling a pro and con list with *benefit*, and found myself searching for *negefit*.

Comment: I think you're more likely to find *dis-* as in *disbenefit* and *mal-* in words like *malefactor* than anything with *neg-*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, *bene-* and *neg-* are not used to form antonyms in either English or Latin.  Their root meanings of "good" and "deny" are roughly opposed, but not antonyms in English either.

As others have mentioned, *mal-*, meaning "bad" is the typical antonym to *bene-*, as in *benediction/malediction* (literally "good speech", "bad speech").

*Posi-* may seem like it should oppose *negi-* because of the *positive/negative* pairing, but it actually comes from a root word meaning "put" or "place."  *Affirm-* is probably a better opposite to *neg-* as in *affirmative/negative* and *affirmation/negation.*

Comment: another example : bonus / malus

Comment: beneficent/maleficent

Comment: @P I find it repeatedly fascinating that *malus* (a bad thing) is also the Latin for *apple.* Presumably that's why the unspecified "fruit of the tree" in Genesis 3 is universally depicted as an apple.

Answer (score 11):

The [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/malefit) finds

> **malefit** A misfortune, a disadvantage.

from their *British & World English Dictionary*, supposedly from the 18th century.  No provenance or examples.

The printed *OED* doesn't record this word, but does have *malefice* meaning either sorcery (first attribution to Chaucer in 1324) marked as archaic or an evil deed or mischief (first attribution to Spenser's poem "Mother Hubberd's Tale" in 1591) marked as obsolete or archaic:

> He crammed them with crumbs of Benefices, And did fill their mouths
>   with meeds of **malefices**

(There's also an obsolete astrological use meaning the obvious thing.)

The *OED* finds both *benefit* and *benefice* from the 1300s.  The former prospered into five major senses (including such as the kind of benefit that's a charity event); the latter fell into obsolescence, taking its antonym with it, perhaps because of its special meaning associated with sorcery.  Note that *malefit* would seem to have arrived long after *benefit*.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about words formed with *neg-*

Comment: "The OED doesn't record this word" - I see [malefit here](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/244660) (£), earliest citation 1755

Comment: @AakashM Thanks.  Alas, no access.  But if you add your find as an answer (including the cite if it's interesting), I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were thinking of nugatory? The [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nugatory) gives

**nugatory** of no value or importance

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user207863! This doesn't really answer the question. OP specifically wanted a _neg_, which this is not. My interpretation is that OP was not thinking of a certain word, merely wanting to know if one existed.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.powerthesaurus.org/benefit+negative/antonyms 
and https://www.powerthesaurus.org/beneficial+negative/antonyms

“Negative” is more often than not accepted as an antonym to the noun “benefit” and the adjective “beneficial” — so it would be appropriate to contrast “One benefit of this procedure” with “One negative of this procedure”; though a phrase like “negative effect” or “negative impact” would be better.